# Enable publisher logs in 8.5

Tags: web8.5, publishing

[According to this article](https://gateway.sdl.com/CommunityKnowledge?articleName=000011195), enabling logs for publishers should be set up like this.
However, that is not the case. How to enable publisher logs in 8.5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After testing, and googling, I found out that this is the way to go for 8.5 also:

https://gateway.sdl.com/CommunityKnowledge?articleName=000012178

Comment: Thanks, @Marko. If you haven't had a chance, feel free to leave feedback on either KB article to have them reviewed and updated? :-)

Comment: I will alvin. Hopefully it will help to someone else.